# How to refer to office365 user using Set-Mailbox in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change a user mailbox to a room mailbox in powershell. I know the basic command is:

```
Set-Mailbox "John" -Type Room
```

When I try to run this, I keep getting an error that says the object can't be found. I've tried running the command as:

```
Set-Mailbox "john@xyz.com' -Type Room
```

and

```
Set-Mailbox "cn=John,DN=xyz,DN=com" -Type Room
```

and both give me the same error. How am I supposed to refer to the user to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried `Get-Mailbox john@xyz.com`? What is the output?

Comment: object could not be found

Comment: If you run `Get-Mailbox -Filter {Name -like 'John*'}`, does it appear? What does it list the alias as?

Comment: it returns a user who appears to be on a different server so i think i may have figured out why it's not working

Comment: Office 365 shouldn't have that issue, to be honest.